# Why do I sometimes have an app.config and other times a binaryname.dll.config file?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, configuration-files

In .NET, after building a project, why do I sometimes have an app.config and other times a binaryname.dll.config file?

Comment: Good question. Also, why is there a binaryname.vshost.exe.config ?

Comment: @Valamas. Because Visual studio hosting process also needs a config file when it starts. Visual Studio hosting process is used for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242202.aspx

Comment: @Valamas: Visual Studio creates a hosting process to improve the debugging experience. The name of this process is `binaryname.vshost.exe` and to ensure this process is correctly configured it uses a copy of the `config` file appropriately renamed to match the name of the hosting process. More information about the hosting process: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242202.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You see it as app.config file during development (in Visual Studio). When deployed (as well as in your bin directory), app.config becomes binaryname.dll/exe.config file (automatically renamed by Visual Studio).

As for the exact reason...there is a good reason not to have it as app.config...for example, if you deploy several applications in the same directory, you would be able to have only one app.config...so there is a good reason to name it binaryname.dll.config.

So the real question is: why is it named app.config and not binaryname.dll.config in the first place?

One of the reasons I can think of is that you can always change your binary output name in project options (so compiler generates .exe file with a name different than your project name), and config file will be copied to correspond to that binary output name. Having it named app.config in the solution is better because you always copy the same file name to some destination file name, without a need to rename that file in solution (which is good especially when that file is under source control). There might be some other reason as well.